# Hausdorffness of $\mathbb{R}$ with cocountable topology

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I know that $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{cocountable})$ is a $T_1$ space, and that it is not $T_2$. It is easy for me to prove that it is $T_1$ (let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, take $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{x\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{y\}$ as the open sets). However, I can't come up with a solid proof for the fact that this space is not $T_2$. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Your title is misleading: *separability* of a space refers to the existence of a countable dense subset. I would change the first word to *Hausdorffness*. To prove the result, use the uncountability of $\Bbb R$ to show that **any** two non-empty open sets have non-empty intersection.

Answer (score 1):

You need only to see how open sets look like. Let $U$ be a nonempty open set $\tau_{\text{co}}$; then $$U=\mathbb R\setminus(\text{countable set})$$

Now, let $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then you can not find two disjoint nonempty open sets $U,V$such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you, I fixed.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed it in the first sentence as well and corrected the misspelling in the displayed line. (+1)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, if I  saw your comment from the beginning I will not write my answer since your comment is enough.  I learned a lot from you.

Comment: Yours is essentially the hint that I would have given had I written an actual answer, so I don’t mind at all: it’s good to have an actual answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I do post question this morning about about construction Bernstein set. I do not know if you got a chance to see or not. I spent long time thinking about and No one even said it is possible or impossible. or even like possible but more complicated. I hope if you can say some thing about it.

Comment: I have seen it, but I’ve not had much time to think about it yet.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you.